# Is area of a polygon independent of the angle formed by its sides?

Tags: area, polygons

Basically, I want to know is there any difference between the area of a regular polygon (equal sides and angle) and a polygon with only equal sides (and equality of angles isn't given). Note that it's given that both the polygons have sides of the same length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Except for the triangle, the area depends on both the angles and the sides.

Take a square and can move two diagonally opposite vertices together, making the area as small as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there is a difference.
These pentagons have the same side lengths but different areas.
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/ConvexPolygon_1000.gif